# Django: Group by date then calculate Sum of amount for each date

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have a django model like. it stores total transactions happened over time periods.

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    amount = models.FloatField()
    seller = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='sells', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    buyer = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='purchased', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

#### my question:

is that how can i find total amount of transactions for each day. for each day it should calculate Sum of all transactions in that day.

I need for example do this for last 7 days.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Found the solution, Query below will work:

```
Transaction.objects.filter().values('created_at__date').order_by('created_at__date').annotate(sum=Sum('amount'))
```

result will be:

```
<QuerySet [{'created_at__date': datetime.date(2019, 1, 3), 'sum': 10000000.0}, {'created_at__date': datetime.date(2019, 1, 4), 'sum': 4367566577.0}]>
```

Comment: What if we want to have sum of amount for a day that has no transaction in result of queryset?

Comment: I do that in python. First, find this queryset results, then will iterate on dates and fill date value if not in this list by zero.